# Coffeescript compiler closing off function too early

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

For some reason, the Coffeescript compiler I'm using (with Rails 3.2.11, gems shown below) is translating this

```
$(".fancybox").each ->
  item_id = this.id
  $(this).dblclick ->
    $(this).fancybox
      href: "items/#{item_id}",
      type: 'ajax'
```

into this

```
  $(".fancybox").each(function() {
    var item_id;

    item_id = this.id;
    $(this).dblclick(function() {});
    return $(this).fancybox({
      href: "items/" + item_id,
      type: 'ajax'
    });
  });
```

When that inner `dblclick` block should look more like this:

```
$(this).dblclick(function() {
  return $(this).fancybox({
    href: "items/" + item_id,
    type: 'ajax'
  });
});
```

How do I prevent this, or get around it to get the compiler to format it correctly?

Using

```
  coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
```

Comment: Might you have mixed spaces and tabs in indentation? The code you pasted translates exactly how you'd expect: http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24(%22.fancybox%22).each%20-%3E%0A%20%20item_id%20%3D%20this.id%0A%20%20%24(this).dblclick%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%24(this).fancybox%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20href%3A%20%22items%2F%23%7Bitem_id%7D%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'ajax'

Comment: @JamieWong Yup, had a tab in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a white space problem.

Comment: One of the reasons I dont like using haml or python its easy to get tripped up by white space. But then again its really my fault in the end. :)

Comment: I feel like it's one of those things you have to get used to. Or like me, don't forget to default Sublime Text 2 to tab with spaces ;)